# How to remove "\t" from a json file using sed command in Linux?

Tags: json, linux, bash, sed, tabs

I am having json file containing multiple "\t" in it, I want to remove these characters from json file as when I am trying to convert this json file into CSV, because of these characters my CSV output disturbing.

I have tried multiple times with trial and error methods.

```
sed -i 's/\t//g' input.json
```

Then I tried;

```
sed -i 's/^\t//g' input.json
```

And then;

```
sed -i 's~\t~~g' input.json
```

But unable to remove this "\t" character from input.json file.

Comment: `sed 's/\t//g' file` removes all tab characters, `sed 's/\\//g' file` will remove all `\ `  characters and `sed 's/\\t//g' file` will remove all occurrences of `\t` in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is special in sed regular expressions. To match it literally, you need to escape it by preceding it by another backslash.

```
echo 'a\tb' | sed 's/\\t//g'
ab
```

Comment: Note that `echo '\t'` will print `\t` while `printf '\t'` will print a tab.   OP's struggles do make it seem like the json doesn't have the tabs, but literal `\t`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the **backslash and "t"** from a file, you can use the sed command in Linux:

```bash
sed 's/\\t//g' input.json
```

Maybe, it's better to use a JSON parser like `jq` to modify JSON files instead of using sed:

```bash
jq 'gsub("\\t";"")' input.json
```

**Note:** You can use the `-i` option in both commands to edit the file in place.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for your help, sed -i 's/\\t//g' input.json solve my issue.